# GCP VM Disk space alert

Tags: monitoring, google-compute-engine, system-monitoring

How can I configure GCPs monitoring suite to look at % disk utilization (in total space used, not IOPs)?

The only "disk used" metric I see in metrics explorer seems to chart some kind of units per second.

My end goal is to set alerts when a disk reaches past a certain threshold, say 85%, before filling up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to GCP console > Monitoring > [alerting policy](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting).
Click on "+ Create Policy" button on the top and "Add Condition" 0 you will see a panel that looks something like this below.

[image: Alerting policy creation details]

Set everything as fallows:

**Target:**

- Resource type: GCE VM Instance
- Metric: Disk Utilization

**Filters:**

- name: name of your disk (a list of all your disks will pop up -
  select one)
- device: name of the partition (the one you want to monitor)
- state: free

**Configuration:**

- Condition: below
- Threshold: 15% (or any other value)
- for: (most recent value to get alert immediately)

Comment: Perfect.  I also had to install the monitoring agent on one, even though it was a GCP provided image.

Comment: Now, everything has changed.